# Multimodule maven project - exclusions in depenedency

Tags: java, maven

I want my ModuleTypeA war to include ModuleBase as a dependency with 'src/main/java/typeA' package Excluded and similarly ModuleTypeB war to include ModuleBase as a dependency with 'src/main/java/typeB' package Excluded.

Here is my project structure:

```
ModuleBase
   |
   |----> src/main/java/base
   |----> src/main/java/typeA
   |----> src/main/java/typeB
   |----> pom.xml

ModuleTypeA
   |
   |----> src/main/java/..
   |----> pom.xml

ModuleTypeB
   |
   |----> src/main/java/..
   |----> pom.xml
```

I am new to Maven and not sure how to achieve that. ModuleBase cannot be a parent project as I need to build a jar for that (can't have packaging type pom) so I can create a top level parent project.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have code for typeA in your ModuleBase? AFAIK you can only exclude packages at a project level, so ModuleBase has to exclude typeA but then it would be excluded for all projects depending on ModuleBase. But question is why have specific code in the base?

Comment: The code in ModuleBase is infrastructure related code which I do not want to mix with other application level code in ModuleTypeA. Yes, I am aware of exclusions at project level but that would not serve the purpose here.

Comment: You could move the code from ModuleBase/../typeA to a seperate project and reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it should look something like this:

```
proj
  + proj-base
    + src/main/java/   // containing base code
    + pom.xml
  + proj-mod-type-a
    + src/main/java/   // containing module a code
    + pom.xml          // dependency to proj-base
  + proj-mod-type-b
    + src/main/java/   // containing module b code
    + pom.xml          // dependency to proj-base
  + proj-a-web
    + src/main/java    // war A source
    + pom.xml          // dependency to proj-base and proj-mod-type-b
  + proj-b-web
    + src/main/java    // war B source
    + pom.xml          // dependency to proj-base and proj-mod-type-a
```

In brief, split your project into meaningful modules, each being a unit for dependency.  Construct your WAR base on the dependency you need.

If `proj-base` is in fact a WAR that you want to reuse its content in other WAR, then you may look closer to behavior of WAR overlay in Maven.  However, I believe the basic idea is still the same: better modularize your project and have appropriate dependencies when constructing your WAR/EAR

Answer (score 1):

First, read this article about dependency exclusions:
[Optional Dependencies and Dependency Exclusions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

If you are building a .war file from ModuleBase, you can make not a dependency but an overlay for ModuleTypeA from ModuleBase and similarly ModuleTypeB war as overlay of ModuleBase. For this, you can use Maven War Plugin:
[Maven War Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html)

This way, for exclusion of a package use this in you pom.xml:

```
<excludes>
   <exclude>src/main/java/typeA</exclude>
</excludes>
```

UPDATE:

I haven't try this yet, but there are two ways possible to exclude a package from .jar.

1) Use [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). Here is an example you can refer to:

[Exclude files with maven assembly does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337930/exclude-files-with-maven-assembly-does-not-work)

2) Use [Maven Jar Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/), check this answer as an example:

[maven-jar-plugin Exclusions Failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557041/maven-jar-plugin-exclusions-failing)

Comment: looks like overlays only support war and zip so I have to build ModuleBase as a war file. I am wondering if something is possible is my ModuleBase is built as jar.

Comment: thanks for the information and links. I guess it seems the cleanest solution would be to restructure my project tree as mentioned by @Adrian.

Answer (score 1):

You could create different assemblies in the ModuleBase and refer to those as system dependecies in ModuleTypeA/B.

You can set the path to a dependency with `<systemPath>../module-base/target/rt.jar</systemPath>`

Maybe [Multiple assemblies from one maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727612/multiple-assemblies-from-one-maven-project) will help you with the assembly topic.